# isdigit and arrays in C

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function that takes the users input as a string then I use the `atoi()` function. I have it working hard coded but it will not work when I put it into a for loop in my `void getUserInput()` function:

```
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            switch(num)
            {
               case 1: 
                    printf("Enter number one: ");
                    break;
               case 2: 
                    printf("Enter number one: ");
                    break;
               case 3: 
                    printf("Enter number one: ");
                    break;
            }

            fgets(input, 50, stdin);

            if(isdigit(input[i]))
            {
              if(isdigit(input[i + 1]))
              {
                if(isdigit(input[i + 2]))
                {
                  printf("Error\n");
                }
                else
                {
                  ...
```

I know that the way I incremented the `isdigit()` is the problem but I do not know another way how to check the first char, then second then third from the users input. Any suggestions on how to increment it?

by the way if this helps:
`char input[50];`

Comment: You should put `\n` at the end of every `printf` format string (or call `fflush`). And you should compile with debugging info and all warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`). BTW, you could use a `for (int k=0; k<...; k++) if (isdigit(input[i+k]))` loop (with the `...` replaced appropriately).

Comment: How about:

`if(!isdigit(input[i) || !isdigit(input[i + 1) || !isdigit(input[i + 2))
    ; // do something
else
    ; // do something else`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - The detail of your comments are substantial enough to be cast as full on answers (just saying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use logical operators instead of nested if's:

```
if(isdigit(input[i]) && isdigit(input[i + 1]) && isdigit(input[i + 2]))
```

Even if this is equivalent, it makes code easier to read and understand. But this is not the problem. You are sure the input has 3 characters, followed by NUL? You should check for this too.

Besides what I said, is pretty hard to find the real problem without making assumptions, as your code is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `input` array is character array.

you can do like this :

```
int len, j;
len = strlen(input);

for(j=0; j<len; j++){
    if(isdigit(input[j]){
      // do what you want
    }else{
      // do something else you want
    }
}
```

Make sure you have included `<string.h>` and `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: I just came back to this: wouldn't this create a loop that if I printed out something it would print out the amount of times of the length of the string? Ex, if the array length was 10 my print statement would output 10 times?

Answer (score 1):

If reading input via [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) the "string" returned might carry a trailing `'\n'` for IXish systems or a combination of `'\n'` and `'\r'` on other systms, which will make [`atoi()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) choke.

To get around this either chop of the trailer by doing:

```
{
  char * pc;
  while (pc = strpbrk(input, "\n\r"))
  {
    *pc = '\0';
  }
}
```

or get rid of using [`atoi()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) and go for [`strtol()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html). [`atoi()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) is <strike>evil</strike> dump/unusable at least if you want to be able to successfully read in `0` as it returns `0` on error.

Comment: _atoi() is evil_.  That's just a little strong, isn't it?

Comment: @ryyker: Uhm, that's a matter of perspective ... - however I adjusted my answer.

Comment: @alk in select cases, the "string" does not carry the trailing `\n` and this solution will lop off the last char.  Maybe `if (len > 0 && input[len-1] == '\n') input[--len] = '\0';`?